# IllegalArgumentException left == right in call to GoogleMap.getProjection() inside getMapAsync()

Tags: android, google-maps, android-support-library, supportmapfragment, android-7.0-nougat

After updating to the latest support libraries (version 24.2.0) and setting the compileSdkVersion to 24, I started seeing an IllegalArgumentException left == right in the call to GoogleMap.getProjection() after rotation.

The initial rendering of the map works and when rotating back to the original orientation, the exception is not thrown. It is only going from the original orientation to another orientation (the exception happens every time the rotation changes from original orientation to new orientation)

Going back to version 23.4.0 of the support libraries with the same code does not exhibit this behavior. So, I am not sure if there is an issue in the latest support libraries (which should have nothing to do with GoogleMap), or the latest version is just exposing a bug in my code.

Both versions use the same Google Play Services (9.4.0).

I have read suggestions that the projection should be accessed inside onMapLoadedCallback, but my assumption would be that calling a method on a GoogleMap instance inside the getMapAsync method would be fine as that is supposed to guarantee the map is ready for use.

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: left == right
        at android.opengl.Matrix.frustumM(Matrix.java:327)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.j(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.l(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.b.b.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.v.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.d.aw.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.cb.onTransact(SourceFile:82)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IProjectionDelegate$zza$zza.getVisibleRegion(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection.getVisibleRegion(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.maps.android.clustering.view.DefaultClusterRenderer$RenderTask.run(DefaultClusterRenderer.java:363)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Relevant snippets below:

```
 public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment
 {
    @Nullable
    private SupportMapFragment m_mapFragment;

    // fragment setup code removed for this snippet

    /** Assign the map fragment variable on resume. This is necessary for orientation change events */
    @Override
    public void onResume ()
    {
       super.onResume();

       // We can get here in (at least) 3 different ways:
       // 1. The first time this fragment is created.
       //       In this case, we will not have a local reference to a map fragment and will will add
       //       it if we are the currently displaying fragment.
       // 2. After rotation
       //       Because the actual map fragment is maintained by our activity, the map fragment will
       //       have been recreated and our reference to it will no longer be valid.
       // 3. After a pause event (such as the device going into power saving mode).
       //       We should still have a reference to the current map fragment and it should be
       //       valid. We can test that by checking if the map fragment is attached. This is done
       //       in the setMapFragment() method.
       //
       final AlbumActivity activity = (AlbumActivity)getActivity();

       Fragment currentFragment = activity.getCurrentItemFragment() ;

       if( m_mapFragment == null && this == currentFragment )
       {
          setMapFragment( activity.getMapFragment() );
       }
       else if ( m_mapFragment != null )
       {
          setMapFragment( activity.getMapFragment() );
       }
       else
       {
          // just update the map 
          updateMap() ;
       }
    }

    private void updateMap()
    {
       if ( m_mapFragment == null )
       {
           return;
       }

       m_mapFragment.getMapAsync( new OnMapReadyCallback()
       {
           @Override
           public void onMapReady( GoogleMap googleMap )
           {
               try
               {
                  googleMap.clear();

                  // Exception thrown here!
                  final Projection projection = googleMap.getProjection() ;
                  final VisibleRegion visibleRegion = projection.getVisibleRegion() ;

                  LatLngBounds mapBounds = visibleRegion.latLngBounds;

                  // more done on map here (markers, etc.)
                }
                catch ( IllegalStateException e )
                {
                  // basically, wait 100 ms and try again. However,
                  // the exception seems to not go away until rotation goes back to original orientation
                  configureAfterDelay();
                }
           }
       } ) ;
    }

    public void setMapFragment ( @Nullable SupportMapFragment mapFragment )
   {
      // The working assumption is that our map fragment, if already added, is added to
      // our current fragment.
      if ( mapFragment != null && mapFragment.isAdded() == false )
      {
         final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getChildFragmentManager();

         // Add the map view to the current view
         fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add( R.id.mapview_container, mapFragment, MAP_FRAGMENT_TAG )
        .commit();

         fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
      }

      m_mapFragment = mapFragment;

      updateMap( );
   }
```

I have seen the following issues posted elsewhere, but have found no solution:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8724

Comment: Any solution yet?

Comment: None yet. Tried with the latest releases and still ran across the issue.

Comment: Any solution for this i am also facing my application.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's super late, but I just ran into this issue today... The issue is when the map has a size of 0 and you try to access the map.Projection.VisibleRegion. The error message literally means that the left of the projection is the same as the right of the projection, which would happen if the map view has a width of 0. To get around it, make sure you only access the VisibleRegion of the map's projection when the mapView has a width > 0.

```
var extent = mapView.Width > 0 ? map.Projection.VisibleRegion.LatLngBounds : null;
```